# TAPI, C#: Detecting key presses on a phones keypad

Tags: c#, tapi

I'm attempting to set up a system where I phone a number, and then to confirm it isn't an answering machine I want the recipient to press a phone key to forward the call. The trouble is I'm struggling to find the event that gets raised for phone key presses.

I imagine it is a tone event but nothing seems to be raising.

I could also do with knowing how to detect what key is pressed as well.

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: TAPI has nothing to do with keypresses. Either you are looking for the normal GUI key events, or you mean something completely different. Are you asking how to detect the *keytones* generated by the *recipient* or the *caller*? Which of them is the "user" you mention?

Comment: By Key press, I mean on the phones keypad on the receiving end, so recipient in this case. Sorry, I'm quite new to TAPI and still getting my head around the telephony jargon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called DTMF tones, TAPI can detect and report them via the [`ITDigitDetectionEvent` interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms729517(v=vs.85).aspx).

You need to setup the appropriate event filter and tell `ITLegacyCallMediaControl::DetectDigits` that you are looking for DTMF.

Comment: Thanks! I had tried that one but hadn't told ITlegacyCallMediaControl about it.